# compare videos duration

Tags: bash

I use `mediainfo my_video.mp4 | grep "Duration"` to get videos duration, my question is:
how to compare tow videos with different duration like ***2 h 25 min*** and ***5 min 29 s*** in pure bash script?
thanks

Comment: Suppose you got the duration of two videos in separate lines (as given by your example), what should the _comparison_ look like? Can you elaborate a bit

Comment: im trying to merge audio + video that must have a same length in ffmpeg command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the *duration* in **milliseconds** by:

```
mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" /path/to/file
```

Or in a more coarse-grained ISO time-format using:

```
mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration/String3%" /path/to/file
```

This will return in format:

> HH:MM:SS.MMM

In general to get the list of available `Inform` variables/parameters, type:

```
mediainfo --Info-Parameters
```

See also similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465301/exporting-video-duration-as-hhmmss-into-csv

#### Alternative solution using `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe`:

See:
[Get total duration of video files in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170961/384422)

Comment: your answer helped me to solve the problem. thank you!